# Why realm is required for some users in beeline connection,even its ensured with ldap authentciation.?

Tags: authentication, jdbc, hive, ldap, beeline

Problem: Why realm is required for some users in beeline connection,even its ensured with ldap authentciation.?

While connecting with beeline,with configured ldap authentication some users connected with without realm and some users connect with realm authentication.This is because of while creating users in active directory ,display name differ with logon name.
During authentication,it can only validate by logon name only,but some users validate also by display name.Actually its only validate by on logon name but here it seems validate by display name.

[image]

Please refer the attached images and provide the ideas if you overcome this.

Thanks,
Mathes

Comment: Some more information is added about this problem in descriptions,share your suggestions if you overcome it.